# Voice memos not being deleted from iTunes

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization

I have iTunes (10.0.1) syncing with my iPhone (4.1) with the Voice Memos option enabled.

I created a single voice memo. I synced the phone and the voice memo transferred correctly. I then deleted it on the iPhone and synced again. iTunes still has the voice memo in the "Voice Memos" playlist. Additionally, when I click the iPhone's "Voice Memo" playlist in iTunes, I see the one file there, but it has an exclamation mark near the number.

I have 2 questions:

- What does this exclamation mark mean? There seems to be no way to get more info about it.
- How can I get iTunes to delete the voice memos when I delete the on the phone?

Answer (score 3):

A workaround that I found, is to go to iTunes Music library, find the voice memo, and then manually delete it from there. After you sync, the Voice Memo playlist will be deleted from underneath your iPhone (in iTunes), so you won't see that file that had an exclamation mark anymore.

Comment: This did not help me because I did not have the option to delete. See [How to delete all voice memos stored in iCloud in one go (if in iTunes Music library, you cannot delete any voice memos)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/411524/how-to-delete-all-voice-memos-stored-in-icloud-in-one-go-if-in-itunes-music-lib).

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the mouse and you should be able to see delete.